# Not able to connect to internet from Amazon EC2 instance linux box

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

In the amazon EC2 instance, i have set the set the inbound/outbound of security group to MY-IP address.

When i try to install the mysql client or some other software, its saying connection timeout.

But when i make the inbound/outbound to anywhere ie 0.0.0.0/00, then i am able to install the software.

But i don't want to expose the EC2 instance requests to everyone.

How to connect to Internet and install the software with restricted security groups. Please can u help out on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to access Internet freely, you should allow outgoing network traffic.

To do so, create an `outbound rule` for `all traffic` to `0.0.0.0/0` in your EC2 Security Group. This is a default setting with EC2 and it shouldn't be a security concern.

Comment: When i restrict the IP address in inbound security group, my application runs dead slow, because of this i get connection time out.
When i remove the IP address restriction, the application works fine.
Can please some one help me on this.

Comment: Hi Basu, please create a new Question as it's a different problem

Answer (score 1):

In Security group, Set the outbound traffic to the below

```
Protocol      Port Range  Source  
All Traffic   All  All    0.0.0.0/0
```